# Why doesn't the Android Studio include the google play store app for tablet AVDs?

Tags: google-play-store, avd-manager

I am using Android Studio 3.5.2
Build #AI-191.8026.42.35.5977832, built on October 30, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.13.6

Some of the virtual devices (the phones) include the Play Store components, but none of the Android TV or Tablet images do. Why is that?

Furthermore, is there a way to add the google play store components to a virtual android image?

Is there somewhere to download an image for an Android tablet or TV that includes the google play store components?